# Typography config issue after upgrade Angular material to version 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-5

After an update of angular material to version 6, all the heading elements (h1-h6) are not getting the right font-family and font-size.

Here is my custom config:

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    // Large, one-off headers, usually at the top of the page.
    $display-4:     mat-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300),
    $display-3:     mat-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400),
    $display-2:     mat-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400),
    $display-1:     mat-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
    // h1
    $headline:      mat-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
    // h2
    $title:         mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500),
    // h3
    $subheading-2:  mat-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
    // h4
    $subheading-1:  mat-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400),
    // Bolder body text.
    $body-2:        mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
    // Base body text.
    $body-1:        mat-typography-level(18px, 20px, 400),
    // Smaller body and hint text.
    $caption:       mat-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),
    // Buttons and anchors.
    $button:        mat-typography-level(18px, 14px, 300),
    // Line-height must be unit-less fraction of the font-size.
    $input:         mat-typography-level(18px, 1.2, 300)
);

@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

Comment: Did you add the `mat-typography` class?

Comment: @Edric I forgot and that was my error, Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my case was the missing of the `mat-typography` class.
When I made the upgrade to angular 6, I created a new project and then I just copied in the modules one by one fixing everything needed following the upgrade.
I just passed the `index.hml` file and forgot to add the `mat-typography` class to the `body` element